# Why is the click event of the custom layout for the Item of the JList component not functioning?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Within the confines of a JPanel, I have fashioned a JList component, its Item rendering implemented in a custom manner. Yet, I have unearthed a predicament wherein the ActionListener of the JList itself functions as intended, while the click events of the viewButton and downloadButton within the custom layout fail to come to fruition. May I inquire as to the cause of this perplexity?

```
this.project = project;
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        searchInput = new PlaceHolderTextField("keyword");
        searchInput.setFont(new Font("JetBrains Mono", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        searchInput.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                    updateListData(searchInput.getText());
                }
            }
        });

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = JBUI.insets(5); // 设置组件之间的间距
        add(searchInput, gbc);

        searchList = new JBList<>(model);
        searchList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION); // 设置多选模式
        String dogNum = SeeyonConfigUtil.getConfig(this.project, CTPConfigs.PROJECT_DOGNUM_KEY);
        searchList.setCellRenderer(new CTPSourceApplyItem(dogNum));

        searchList.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                System.out.println("List clicked");
            }
        });

        JBScrollPane scrollPane = new JBScrollPane(searchList);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(scrollPane, gbc);
```

```
public CTPSourceApplyItem(String dogNum) {
        this.dogNum = dogNum;
        setLayout(new GridLayoutManager(1, 4));

        checkBox = new JBCheckBox();
        sourceLabel = new JBLabel();
        viewButton = new JButton("view");
        downloadButton = new JButton("download");

        sourceLabel.setFont(new Font("JetBrains Mono", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        viewButton.setFont(new Font("JetBrains Mono", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        downloadButton.setFont(new Font("JetBrains Mono", Font.PLAIN, 15));

        viewButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("View");
        });

        downloadButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("download");
        });

        add(checkBox, new GridConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1,
                GridConstraints.ANCHOR_WEST, GridConstraints.FILL_NONE,
                GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED,
                null, null, null));

        add(sourceLabel, new GridConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1,
                GridConstraints.ANCHOR_CENTER, GridConstraints.FILL_BOTH,
                GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_WANT_GROW, GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED,
                null, null, null));

        add(viewButton, new GridConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1,
                GridConstraints.ANCHOR_EAST, GridConstraints.FILL_NONE,
                GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED,
                null, null, null));

        add(downloadButton, new GridConstraints(0, 3, 1, 1,
                GridConstraints.ANCHOR_EAST, GridConstraints.FILL_NONE,
                GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED, GridConstraints.SIZEPOLICY_FIXED,
                null, null, null));
    }
```

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem and use standard JDK classes so we can test the code. *the ActionListener of the JList itself functions as intended,* - a JList doesn't support an ActionListener.